# dev site running on subdomain is redirecting to the main domain

Tags: server, hosting

I wanted to create a dev site for my main wordpress site. So I copied my wordpress files to the virtual host server and imported the database from my main site. Then I ran `wp search-replace 'www.mobisium.com' 'dev.mobisium.com'` (main site= 'www.mobisium.com' dev='dev.mobisium.com') to change the database url's.
Then I created a dns for dev.mobisium.com using cloudflare. But now when I visit dev.mobisium.com it redirects me to the main domain mobisium.com. I don't know much about wordpress and server management. I just followed my colleague instructions.

Solutions I tried:

- tried adding `define('WP_HOME','http://subdomain.example.com');` `define('WP_SITEURL','http://subdomain.example.com');` to wp-config file.
- adding home and site URL in wp_options in the database, but there is no home and site URL in wp_options in the database.

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. I hope you find the answer(s) you are looking for. Our site is different from most - if you have not done so yet, consider checking out the [tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to find out how things work.